# displaying listbox in grid

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, grid, stackpanel

This might be a stupid question, but i'm stuck doing it :(. I have a grid and have 3 columns. I have a textbox and a listbox in each of these 3 columns as shown:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="130"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="380"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="146"></ColumnDefinition>
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                <TextBox Text="File Name" Height="30"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
                <TextBox Text="File Path" Height="30"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0">
                <TextBox Text="File Size" Height="30"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                <ListBox Name="listbox_name" Margin="1,30" Height="276" />
             </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                <ListBox Name="listbox_path" Margin="1,30" Height="276" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="2">
                <ListBox Name="listbox_size" Margin="1,30" Height="276" />
            </StackPanel>
```

and the code behind it:

```
public Window1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();

        list.Add("D:\\a\\hy");
        list.Add("D:\\a\\hy1");
        list.Sort();           
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        listbox_name.ItemsSource = list;
        grid1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        grid1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

But on the click of the button, im not able to see the listboxes, with the list displayed. Please guide me as to where im going wrong. Thanks!

Comment: why are you using so many stack panels to display headers... 
Just Use ListView and use a GridView inside it and make GridView Columns....

Comment: hi,@adcool2007 i'm new so i dint know how to go about. will try your method too thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that your `stackPanel` is in `Grid.Col="0"` and it is very small. But `ListBox` is inside of your `stackPanel`. It has a margin and it goes down. Is you can't see your `listBox`.

[image]

If you will do something like this:

```
<StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,-279">
            <ListBox Name="listbox_name" Margin="1,30" Height="276" />
        </StackPanel>
```

you will see your listBox and it will work.

**NOTE:** this code is only example. You need to make a better layout for your window.

Here is how i made a window loyout:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="678" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid Name="grid1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="130"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="380"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="146"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="File Name"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5" />
        <TextBlock Text="File Path"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" />
        <TextBlock Text="File Size" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="5" />

        <ListBox Name="listbox_name" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="Black" />
        <ListBox Name="listbox_path" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="Black" />
        <ListBox Name="listbox_size" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Black" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, @sergey: Thanks, that works perfectly! :) but how about the other two? How can i display them? As in all 3 together?

Comment: Hi, @sergey: yeah this is exactly what i needed, thanks! :) Ive got an expander, how do i make the grid visible (and the window resized to fit the grid) when the expander is expanded? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: But in this, the grid space is shown even though the expander is not expanded. How do i get the window to increase in size when the expander is clicked?

Comment: Hmmm. now i've given my window Height="181" Width="Auto" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight". My button and expander are outside grid1. When i expand the expander, the window size does increase but the grid comes on top of the button and expander. How can i avoid that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
    <ListView Name="list"
              Grid.Row="1" 
              ItemsSource={Binding Path=Files}                
              >
    <ListView.View>        
     <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Name">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button>
                     <TextBlock Text="{BindingPath=Name}"/>                            
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Size">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button>
                     <TextBlock Text="{BindingPath=Size}"/>                            
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Path">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button>
                     <TextBlock Text="{BindingPath=Path}"/>                            
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
     </ListView.View>  
    </ListView>
```

## My your ViewModel will be

```
public class FileListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<Fileinfo> Files{ get; set; }

    private Fileinfo selectedFile;

    public Fileinfo SelectedFile
    {
        get { return selectedFile; }
        set
        {
            selectedFile= value;
            InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedFile"));
        }
    }

    public PersonListViewModel()
    {
                //Loading List
                   Files= new ObservableCollection<Fileinfo>()
              {    //This is temp list you modify accordinh to you logic
                                   new FileInfo{Name = "File32"},
                                   new FileInfo{Name = "File33"},
                                   new FileInfo{Name = "File373"},
                                   new FileInfo{Name = "File393"},
                                   new FileInfo{Name = "File345"},
                                   new FileInfo{Name = "File375"},
                                   new FileInfo{Name = "File395"},
                                   new FileInfo{Name = "File387"},
                                   new FileInfo{Name = "File387"}
                               };
    }

    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

## Your Model should be like

```
public class FileinFo: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string size;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string name;
    private bool isSelected;

    public string Size
    {
        get { return size; }
        set
        {
            size= value;
            InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("size"));
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }



    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            isSelected = value;
            InvokePropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSelected"));
        }
    }

    public void InvokePropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }
}
```

You need to set the datacontext of yor View to ViewModel

so lets say your view is named as FileListView.xaml

Then in code behind in the Constructor you can write

```
this.DataContext= new FileListViewModel();
```

Comment: Hi adcool, i know i'm late but im trying the method you suggested as my requirements say so. I'm not sure if this is possible, but is there a way in a listview that i can display an arraylist onto it? Do i need binding to a class? Thanks!

Comment: @user877852 is your array List have Objects of same type. then just use ItemsSource= {Binding Path=ListOfObjects}.... Also if the Objects are of same types... use generic List<>

Comment: hi @adcool, sorry but i'm new to this. I have three arraylists. I put each of them under different objects(name,path and size) and i bind them using <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path= name}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"/> I still dont get the correct resutlt. how can i go ahead? Thanks!